# How to implement communication for calculating total Shopping Cart between components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

how to make bewtween components get the result of total shopping cart when client increement or decrement stock in Vue js ?

i have 3 components in this case

1. one is `header/navbar.vue` which has icon **cart** / i am using  modal.
2. `shop.vue` for add to cart,
3. and `detail.vue` has add to cart also

i already be able to add cart in the shop.vue and add it to database, but i don't know how to make them communication when client increst the stock, and also when client add to cart for several times, the item i make is one by one 
like 
when client add cart item1 , and then it show on  1 stock cart basket, the item one, and client add to cart again the item1 with stock one , it gonna add to cart basken also, it doesnt make the item to be `item1 2 stocks`, i don't know how to make them automatically to be like that
here is some code from my

```
 addcart(val) {
 this.$axios
          .post(
            '/api/cart/addcart',
            {
              item: val,
              amount: 1,
            },
            {
              headers: token,
            },
          )
          .then(({ data }) => {
            console.log('added')
          })
          .catch(err => {
            this.$swal.fire({
              type: 'error',
              text: err.response.data.error,
            });
          });
      }
```

and on my header/navbar/ to fet the cart, i fecth the data from server to get user id cart shoing on cart icon
i am suing MongoDB , Mongoose for server and database 
is there any simple example to make beteween component comunivation to get recenive and send data for this case ????

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but it sounds like you should be using [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/). This allows components to share data between one another.

Comment: is there any alernative beside using Vuex??

Comment: You could use an [Event Bus](https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/)

Answer (score 0):

You might consider to create a common owner component to share the state between those component, from the [Thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html):

> For each piece of state in your application:
>
> · Identify every component that renders something based on that state.
>
> · Find a common owner component (a single component above all the components that need the state in the hierarchy).
>
> ·Either the common owner or another component higher up in the hierarchy should own the
> state.
>
> ·If you can’t find a component where it makes sense to own the
> state, create a new component simply for holding the state and add it
> somewhere in the hierarchy above the common owner component.

In your case, your component can be nested under a common owner component:

```
Container.vue/
│
├── Navbar.vue /
│
├── Shop.vue /
│
├── Detail.vue /
```

If you updating your cartItem in Shop.vue, you can updated your result by using [emit](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Listening-to-Child-Components-Events)

I create a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/132v86qm4q) to repeat your problem.

Here is the link: https://codesandbox.io/s/132v86qm4q

Hope I solve your problems!

Comment: thanks for your help, i was solve my problem like what you did, but for same item, it keep adding, i want the the same item increment the value, when i click item1 and i click item1 again, it should be item1 equal 2 quantity

Comment: Sorry for late reply, the codesandbox link has updated.
I added another button on each cartItem, for adding the each cartItem quantity; and I changed the data structure of cartItem in Container.vue, from Array to Object.
It should be solved your problem.

Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/132v86qm4q